# Flutter Image Cropp Doesnt show Image

Tags: flutter

I use Flutter Image Crop, Image editing working but doesnt show image. I press the button. I choose the picture. I'm arranging. Then I hit the 'check' button. However, the picture does not appear on the screen.I don't know what to do. I've been working on it for 2 days but I couldn't find the error.

```
 import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
runApp(cropBen1());
}

class cropBen1 extends StatelessWidget {
const cropBen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
title: "Image Cropper Ben",
home: cropBen2(),
);
}
}

class cropBen2 extends StatefulWidget {
const cropBen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<cropBen2> createState() => _cropBen2State();
}

class _cropBen2State extends State<cropBen2> {
File? _image,imageFile;


Future getImage(ImageSource source) async{
try {
final image=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
if(image==null) return;

final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
this._image=imageTemporary;
_cropImage(image?.path);

} on PlatformException catch (e) {
print('Failed to pick image : $e');
}

}

_cropImage(filePath) async {
final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(sourcePath: filePath,maxHeight: 1080,maxWidth: 1080);
if (croppedImage != null) {
imageFile = croppedImage as File?;
setState(() {});
}
}




@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(centerTitle:true,title: Text("Image Cropper Ben"),),
body: Center(child: Column(children: [
SizedBox(height: 30,),
Container(child: imageFile != null ? Image.file(imageFile!,width: 300,height: 300,fit: BoxFit.cover,)
: Image.network('http://gezilecekyerler.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/van.jpg'),),
SizedBox(height: 20,),
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: ()=>{getImage(ImageSource.gallery)},
child: Container(
width: 250,
height: 50,
child: Row(children: [
Icon(Icons.image_outlined),
SizedBox(width: 20,),
Text("Resim Yükle",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 24),),
],),
)),
],),),
);
}
}



AndroidManifest.XML

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deneme_flutter">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label="deneme_flutter"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity
           android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add the required dependencies in android manifest ?

Comment: Add AndroidManifest.xml